# Зачем выносить стили в head?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, style

Знаю что есть такая практика, когда некие части CSS кода выносятся в `<head>`. Я так понимаю, что это на случай если файл стилей не загрузится. Но какие именно части нужно выносить, и нужно ли вообще это делать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы проверяли ваш сайт через `PageSpeed Insights`, то должны были заметить, одной из рекомендаций есть

> Убрать js или css который блокирует рендеринг страницы

Поскольку браузер выполняет все последовательно, он сначала будет загружать стили подключенные в `head`, а после продолжит рендерить страницу. Данный способ приемлем когда есть большая скорость интернета, но если она низкая мы не увидим страницу до загрузки стилей.

Поэтому, их рекомендуют загружать после, а в `head` добавить базовые стили через тег `style`, которые позволят воспринимать содержимое страницы до полной загрузки всех файлов.

Как пример, можно спрятать картинки,svg, рекламные блоки или ограничить их размер.

Comment: Т.е получается мы пишем в `head` такие стили, которые бы грубо говоря ускорили загрузку страницы

Answer (score 0):

Если стили будут внизу, то покажется сначала сайт БЕЗ CSS. Потом они загрузятся и выйдет не очень. Писать в `head` это мировая практика.

Comment: И причем здесь ваш ответ к вопросу автора? И почему если стили загрузятся после рендеринга `html` будет "не очень"?

Answer (score -2):

Стили можно загрузить почти в любой момент. Размещение в HEAD обусловлено тем, что так их проще найти. Встречал в практике случаи загрузки стилей в конце страницы (можно считать в подошве). Из-за этого сайты начинали "плыть" после полной загрузки.